# How to merge text layers without converting text to shapes or rasterizing them in PS CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers

Every time I create a text box in Photoshop using the Type Tool, it puts the text box in a separate layer. Is there a way to merge text layers to better manage a group of text boxes?

The options I've seen to merge them involve converting the text to shapes or rasterizing them but after doing this I can no longer keep editing the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way I would recommend you did this. That's by actually creating a folder with the name Text Box and placing all the text boxes inside it, this way you will have only one layer in the panel when the folder is closed, saving you space, but when you open it you will still have each text box intact and editable.

Some people might say to select all of the text boxes, right click on them and convert them into smart object...this works too, kinda, it does "merge" all the text boxes inside one smart object and when you double click the smart object, another window opens with all the text, you can edit it, close the window and save and the changes will happen in your document but there's a downside to it when it comes to arranging the text boxes in new positions, new widths and heights. It's kinda hard to handle therefore I don't quite recommend using this method for text.